Are Win API CopyFIleEx Copy Operations Atomic When Replacing a File?
Hi I have a simple question - are Win API CopyFIleEx copy operations atomic when replacing a file? So if you are replacing a destination file and the computer crashes in the middle of the copy operation, is the destination file that was being overwritten preserved? Thanks!

Why would there be CopyFileTransacted if it was?

Wasn't aware of that guy or transactional NTFS. Thanks.

Don't use transactional NTFS, they say.

Yup see here for you googlers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/deprecation-of-txf

I wasn't suggesting that you call CopyFileTransacted. I was repeating the part of the documentation that helps you answer your own question.

As @IInspectable pointed out, there is CopyFileTransacted.
Also according to Alternatives to using Transactional NTFS, you already know,

TxF was introduced with Windows Vista as a means to introduce atomic
file transactions to Windows.

